# Breaking down gamma PnL by time

Tags: options, option-pricing, finance-mathematics, quants

Let's say in one day time, underlying price S goes up by $2.4. Then the gamma PnL should be

$\frac{1}{2}\gamma_0 (2.4)^2$. Let's assume that in every hour the underlying goes up by $0.1. Then how do we breakdown this gamma PnL by hour? Or how much gamma PnL are we making every hour?

Comment: if you actually have more frequent market data, then why break down / allocate the daily figures - why not recalculate the fair value and all the greeks every hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are hedging your portfolio fully every hour, there are mutliple ways to attribute gamma PnL here, all of them are correct and incorrect at the same time. Your delta PnL is also coming from gamma since the deltas you accumulate is a consequence of gamma (ignoring other second order spot Greeks). Just decide on a frequency you want to report the Greek PnL at and keep it consistent that way. Best way is to keep it a function of your hedging frequency.